# Select 1 to n relationship "the wrong way arround"

Tags: python, sqlite

`products`:

| productid | price |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |

`orders`:

| orderId | address |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | lala |
| 1 | lala |

`orderedProducts`:

| productid | orderId | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

I want to get:

```
orders[
   {id, address, items[{productid , price, amount}, {productid , price, amount}]},
   {id, address, items[{productid , price, amount}]}
]
```

Is that possible with a single query? I am using SQLite with Python.

Comment: Do you want to get back ```items``` in JSON object? 
Like this: ```[{"productid" : 1, "price" : 20, "amount" : 2}]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **json_group_array** and **json_object**. Documentation for usage is [here](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)

Your query could be this:

```
SELECT
  o.id AS order_id,
  o.address,
  json_group_array(
    json_object(
      'productid', p.id,
      'price', p.price,
      'amount', op.amount
    )
  ) AS items
FROM
  orders o
LEFT JOIN
  orderedProducts op ON o.id = op.orderId
LEFT JOIN
  products p ON op.productid = p.id
GROUP BY
  o.id, o.address;
```

You have to use `GROUP BY o.id, o.address` because of the `json_group_array`

To make some demo queries feel free to use this [site](https://sqliteonline.com/).

Mock data creation:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  price INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  address VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE orderedProducts (
  productid INTEGER REFERENCES products(id),
  orderId INTEGER REFERENCES orders(id),
  amount INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO products (id, price) VALUES (0, 10), (1, 20);
INSERT INTO orders (id, address) VALUES (0, 'lala'), (1, 'lala');
INSERT INTO orderedProducts (productid, orderId, amount) VALUES (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group_concat/), something like this:

```sql
SELECT   
  o.orderId,   
  o.address,  
  '[' || GROUP_CONCAT('{"id": ' || p.productid || ', "price": ' || p.price || ', "amount": ' || op.amount || '}', ', ') || ']' as items  
FROM orders o  
JOIN orderedProducts op ON o.orderId = op.orderId  
JOIN products p ON op.productid = p.productid  
GROUP BY o.orderId, o.address;
```

Here's an example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/80db4/2/0)